# stl library:I am new to stl library and facing compilation error

Tags: c++, stl

In this program i am getting error at the marked line.

I am new to stl library and so having trouble understanding it.
In the below code I am trying to use stl library of vector and list and trying to make adjacency list

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

void add_vertex(vector< list<int> > *adjlist)
{
    adjlist->push_back(list<int>());//adding vertex
}

void add_edge(vector< list<int> > *adjlist,int x,int y)
{
    adjlist[x].push_back(y); //adding edge
    // ^^^^ some error here ^^^^
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int t,n,i,j;
    int s[500],d[500];
    int max =0,tmpl;
    //int vertex[500] ={0,};

    vector< list<int> > adjlist;//adjacency list

    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(j =0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d %d",&s[j],&d[j]);

            tmpl = (s[j]>d[j])?s[j]:d[j];
            if(max < tmpl)
                max = tmpl;
        }

        for(j =0;j<max;j++)
        {
            add_vertex(&adjlist);

        }
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            add_edge(&adjlist,s[j],d[j]);//adding edge into the list
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Unless you tell us **what** is the error we will have great trouble telling you how to fix it

Comment: There is no bold line. I guess the bold markup was lost during copy and paste.

Comment: Instead of passing pointers, pass a reference to `adjlist` in you function.

Answer (score 2):

In function add_edge change this statement

```
adjlist[x].push_back(y);
```

to

```
( *adjlist )[x].push_back(y);
```

But in any case it would be better to define the function and other similar functions 
as having the first parameter of type reference to vector than pointer to vector. For example

```
void add_edge( vector< list<int> > &adjlist, int x, int y )
{
    adjlist[x].push_back(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `c` syntax in passing variables , for `c++` use `&` (additional benifit , it will not create a new copy) .

This compiles :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

    void add_vertex(vector< list<int> > &adjlist)
    {

        adjlist.push_back(list<int>());//adding vertex

    }

    void add_edge(vector< list<int> > &adjlist,int x,int y)
    {


        adjlist[x].push_back(y);//adding edge

    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        int t,n,i,j;
        int s[500],d[500];
        int max =0,tmpl;
        //int vertex[500] ={0,};

        vector< list<int> > adjlist;//adjacency list

        scanf("%d",&t);

        for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&n);
            for(j =0;j<n;j++)
            {
                scanf("%d %d",&s[j],&d[j]);

                tmpl = (s[j]>d[j])?s[j]:d[j];
                if(max < tmpl)
                    max = tmpl;
            }

            for(j =0;j<max;j++)
            {
                add_vertex(adjlist);

            }
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                add_edge(adjlist,s[j],d[j]);//adding edge into the list
            }
        }
        return 0;

    }
```